# Lighttpd Reverse Proxy with Pi-hole

Tags: reverse-proxy, lighttpd

Aware this question has being asked a few times and I've read a lot of the solutions but I still cannot get my reverse proxy to work.

I have a Raspberry Pi with Pi-hole.

```
Hostname: pi-hole.local
IP address: 192.168.1.254
Lighttpd port: 8080
```

I want to visit http://pi-hole.local in my browser without `:8080` and view the Pi-hole admin page.

ATM, I have to type http://pi-hole.local:8080.

I have added `mod_proxy` to:

```
server.modules = (
   ...
   mod_proxy
   ...
)
```

I have `server.port = 8080` and I have this block:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "pi-hole.local" {   
  proxy.server  = ( "" => ("" => ( "host" => "192.168.1.254", "port" => 8080 ))) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pi-hole.local is the URI authority, not the url-path.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "pi-hole.local" {   
  proxy.server  = ( "" => ("" => ( "host" => "192.168.1.254", "port" => 8080 ))) 
}
```

Separately, for http://pi-hole.local to work, lighttpd also needs to be listening on port 80.  Is that the case on your system?  Is something else listening on port 80?  If not, then `$SERVER["socket"] == "*:80" {}` will have lighttpd additionally listening on port 80, in addition to `server.port = 8080`.  However, I have not looked into how pi-hole uses this, so you should test that pi-hole still works the way you want it to.

Instead of mod_proxy, a better way might be mod_redirect.

```
server.modules += ("mod_redirect")
$HTTP["host"] =~ "pi-hole.local" {   
  url.redirect = ("" => "http://pi-hole.local:8080${url.path}${qsa}")
}
```